# Design an SMPS to provide 5V – Transformer

Tags: transformer, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, component-selection

I'm trying to design an integrated IoT device that will replace standard light switches. Currently I'm using a Switching Power Supply from eBay: HLK-PM01, just to have an working prototype. Now I spend over a week searching for example schematics, IC and others to create my own small switching psu, but really I'm quite unsure how to begin with.

I need to provide around 300 mA 5V from 240V AC in my whole circuit. I've got an ATmega168PA, nRF24L01+ and other less important components, like status diodes and one analog sensor to power. I'm building the psu on my own to have the possibility to arrange those components on the PCB a bit more and to gain more knowledge about those modules.

Found out that an IC from the TNY263-268 family, from Power Integrations should fit my needs, but now my problem is:

> What type (*something like EF12.6 or EE13..?*) and from where could I purchase a complete transformer that will fit into my circuit?

Often most examples mention discrete component values, but those transformers aren't really described.

Maybe I'm horrible wrong with all this, but I'm open to all suggestions and advices I can possible get.

Comment: What is your input voltage ? From the module you mentioned, I assume it's from the mains.

Comment: You can sarcifice some cellphone PSUs ?

Comment: Yes, European mains 240V. If I'm desperate enough, I'll sacrifice some 5v psu's, but I thought that some component deliverers should provide prebuild transformer solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe I'm horrible wrong with all this, but I'm open to all
>   suggestions and advices I can possible get.

I would look no further than Premier Magnetics - they support a large number of Power Integrations designs such as this universal one that uses the TNY-255: -

[image]

[This page](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html) will take you to various options for off-line SMPS designs and if you click on [UL-CSA Recognized - TinySwitch Transformers](http://www.premiermag.com/pdf/pny.pdf) it will deliver the TNY options.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great response, but it's a pity that those transformers aren't available for purchase from European sellers.

Comment: [Avnet Abacus is an authorised Premier Magnetics distributor throughout Europe](https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/abacus/products/manufacturers/premier-magnetics/) all you have to do is google it. Not hard really.

Comment: And if they don't supply it, reverse engineering it to suit another ferrite core set is not challenging.

Comment: They do sell it but in qty 100 at under 2 euro. How many do you want? Maybe they can send you a sample to evaluate?

Comment: Alright, currently I'm thinking about 10-ish just for prototyping. I'll try to reach them, but maybe I find transformers that'll match those datasheets from PremierMagnetics. Thank You.